# Post request in express in not accepting request body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I tried everything to get my request body in POST method. I'm using postman with raw and form-data mode. Tried calling this API from react too nothing works. `console.log(req.body)` prints blank. {}
do let me know what I am missing.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const port = 9000
const enableWs = require('express-ws');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Comment: What is the precise request you're sending to your server, including all headers?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I recreated your app, and it actually works.

I am using insomnia to test your api.
To the route "/" with Post, and some JSON.
Then in the Console.log I get the request body.

[image: Insomnia API test to POST]

Console.log

[image: console.log for api]

Maybe you are testing incorrectly? Please get back to me if there is any question.

My guess is that you are not passing anything in your POST request, hence the empty body.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to specify `Content-Type` to `application/json` in postman's request headers.

In order for body-parser to parse `req.body` from JSON, your request must specify that the content is, in fact, JSON. Otherwise, it will not parse it; resulting in your blank `req.body`.

```js
fetch('http://localhost:9000', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'hi',
    }),
})
```